# Mock Method inside another class

Tags: mocking, mockito, junit4

Here am try to spy a method In that its externally calls another method. All  I need is to mock the external method. Below is my simulation of my project kind of legacy project

```
public class TestClass {
    public int dependencyOne(){
        System.out.println("Need to mock Externally ");
        return  100;
    }
    public int methodNeedTobeTested(int a){
        int c = new AnotherClass().dependencyTwo();
        return a + this.dependencyOne() + c;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass {
    public int dependencyTwo(){
        System.out.println("Need to mock externally");
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Here is my Test Case

```
public class TestClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    TestClass testClass;

    @Mock
    AnotherClass anotherClass;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule initRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Test
    public void methodNeedTobeTested() {
        testClass = Mockito.spy(new TestClass());
        Mockito.when(anotherClass.dependencyTwo()).thenReturn(10);
        Mockito.doReturn(10).when(testClass).dependencyOne();
        assertEquals(testClass.methodNeedTobeTested(10),30);
    }
}
```

My Output :

Need to mock externally

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :30
Actual   :120

what am Missing?

Dependency :

```
byte-buddy-1.10.11.jar
cglib-nodep-3.2.9.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar
junit-4.12.jar
mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
mockito-core-2.23.0.jar
objenesis-3.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

To mock the call to the `AnotherClass`, you should not create an instance using `new` inside your application code. This will always instantiate the *real* object and you are not able to mock it.

A better approach would be to take an instance of `AnotherClass` as part of the constructor of `TestClass` and follow inversion of control (e.g. use the Spring Framework of [CDI](https://rieckpil.de/whatis-contexts-and-dependency-injection-cdi/) to have dependency injection).

```
public class TestClass {

    public AnotherClass anotherClass;

    public TestClass(AnotherClass anotherClass) {
       this.anotherClass = anotherClass;
    }

    public int dependencyOne(){
        System.out.println("Need to mock Externally ");
        return  100;
    }

    public int methodNeedTobeTested(int a){
        int c = anotherClass.dependencyTwo();
        return a + this.dependencyOne() + c;
    }
}
```

With this approach your test should work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion , But with the help of PowerMockito , I can able to mock this or
Is powermockito is bad practice ?

Comment: A more clean approach would be to follow inversion of control and make use of dependency injection. I see PowerMockito as a bad practice most likely as this allows bad design of your application